# TextOut() function displays text but text disappears as the window is Minimized or restored

Tags: winapi, text, window, textout

I am unsing TextOut() Function to display some text in my window. It works fine and text is displayed as soon as the Window is Maximized.But as Soon as the Window is Minimized and restored again, all text displayed on window disappears :(
Is there any way in which I can retain data displayed on my window even if it is Minimized?
Waiting for response :(

Comment: what windowing system are you using?  Update your tags

Comment: i am using WIN32 API in MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 2008

Comment: It sounds like you are drawing outside your paint loop. When the window is minimized and restored, you will get a `WM_PAINT` message asking you to redraw your content. You need to draw the text in your `WM_PAINT` handler if you want it to be retained when restored.